# Transaction complete page sends two emails when it should send one

Tags: php, payment-gateway

I use the Payson payment gateway and after completing the payment when the user is redirected back to the thank you page, two of the same emails are sent to the user. Please help me to solve this issue.Code is below:

```
$select="select * from #__content where id=12 and state=1";

$db->setQuery($select);
$result = $db->loadObject();

echo $result->introtext;
//echo $_REQUEST['id'];

$select = "select * from #__booking order by id desc";
$db->setQuery($select);
$db->query();
$id=$db->loadObject();

$insert_id=$id->id;
$printid=base64_encode($insert_id);

        $db=& JFactory::getDBO();
        $select_brand="select * from #__booking where id=".$id->id."";
        $db->setQuery($select_brand);
        $result = $db->loadObject();

        $db=& JFactory::getDBO();
        $select_brand="select * from #__brand where published=1 and id=".$result->brand."";
        $db->setQuery($select_brand);
        $result_brand = $db->loadObject();

        $select_model="select * from #__modno where published=1 and id=".$result->model."";
        $db->setQuery($select_model);
        $result_model = $db->loadObject();


        $printlink=JURI::root()."print.php?id=".$insert_id;
        $link="http://www.status.repair24.se/?id=".$insert_id;
        $phoneimagelink=JURI::root()."templates/mobile/images/phicon.png";
        $logolink=JURI::root()."templates/mobile/images/2.png";
        $to= $result->email;
        $subject = "Invoice Mail";
        $body.='<center><div style="width:100%;background-color:#f1f3f6;"><br>
                        <table bgcolor="#dde1e8" cellpadding="10" width="70%" style="border:1px solid #000;">
                            <tr><td>
                                <table bgcolor="white" align="center" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="5" width="100%" style="border:1px solid #000;">
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <table width="100%">
                                            <tr>
                                                <td align="left"><img src="'.$logolink.'" width="200"></td>
                                                <td align="right"><img src="'.$phoneimagelink.'"  style="margin:3px 5px -3px 0" alt="" border="0">123456789</td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </table>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>

                                <tr>
                                    <td style="font-size:12px;font-family:Arial;" align="left">
                                        Name : '.$result->name.'
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td style="font-size:12px;font-family:Arial;" align="left">
                                        Address: '.$result->address.'
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td style="font-size:12px;font-family:Arial;" align="left">
                                        Zip Code: '.$result->zip.'
                                    </td>
                                </tr>

                                <tr>
                                    <td style="font-size:12px;font-family:Arial;" align="left">
                                        Mobile : '.$result->mobile.'
                                    </td>
                                </tr>

                                <tr>
                                    <td style="font-size:12px;font-family:Arial;" align="left">
                                        Email : '.$result->email.'
                                    </td>
                                </tr>

                                <tr>
                                    <td style="font-size:12px;font-family:Arial;" align="left">
                                        Brand : '.$result_brand->name.'
                                    </td>
                                </tr>

                                <tr>
                                    <td style="font-size:12px;font-family:Arial;" align="left">
                                        Model: '.$result_model->name.'
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td style="font-size:12px;font-family:Arial;" align="left">
                                        Size '.$result->size.'
                                    </td>
                                </tr>

                                <tr>
                                    <td style="font-size:12px;font-family:Arial;" align="left">
                                        Imei  : '.$result->imei.'
                                    </td>
                                </tr>

                                <tr>
                                    <td style="font-size:12px;font-family:Arial;" align="left">
                                        Operator : '.$result->operator.'
                                    </td>
                                </tr>


                                <tr>
                                    <td style="font-size:12px;font-family:Arial;" align="left">
                                        Lock CODE : '.$result->lockcode.'
                                    </td>
                                </tr>

                                <tr>
                                    <td style="font-size:12px;font-family:Arial;" align="left">
                                        Error Descriptions : '.rtrim($result->repairs,',').'
                                    </td>
                                </tr>

                                <tr>
                                    <td style="font-size:12px;font-family:Arial;" align="left">
                                        Price : '.$result->price.' SEK
                                    </td>
                                </tr>

                                <tr>
                                    <td style="font-size:12px;font-family:Arial;" align="left">
                                        Repair Number : '.$result->num.'
                                    </td>
                                </tr>



                                <tr>
                                    <td style="font-size:12px;font-family:Arial;" align="left">
                                        <a href='.$printlink.'>Click here </a>to print Your Booking Details.
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td style="font-size:12px;font-family:Arial;" align="left">
                                        <a href='.$link.'>Click here </a>to check status.
                                    </td>
                                </tr>




                            </table></td></tr></table><br><br></div></center>';


        // To send HTML mail, the Content-type header must be set
    $from = array("info@repair24.se", "Repair 24");
 // To send HTML mail, the Content-type header must be set
        # Invoke JMail Class
    $mailer = JFactory::getMailer();

    # Set sender array so that my name will show up neatly in your inbox
    $mailer->setSender($from);

    # Add a recipient -- this can be a single address (string) or an array of addresses
    $mailer->addRecipient($to);

    $mailer->setSubject($subject);
    $mailer->setBody($body);

    # If you would like to send as HTML, include this line; otherwise, leave it out
    $mailer->isHTML(1);

    # Send once you have set all of your options
    $ma=$mailer->send();
```

Comment: Hi there! As it stands right now, it's almost impossible for us to help you. You need to show some code, configuration, whatever it is that you use to send emails.

Comment: This is joomla site so we use simple joomla mail function but why 2 same mail send without any loop or page not load 2 times can u please told me the reason.

Comment: No, we can't, since we don't know what you're doing, what it looks like, what code runs, what the redirect looks like, if there's another callback that's being called, etc etc.

Comment: I add the total code that i write in thank you page for send mail

Answer (score 0):

.. I am facing the same problem with similar code (on Joomla 2.5)!

I may also add that some email addresses are ALWAYS received as single while others are ALWAYS received as twin. It seems to me that it is not a problem due to the code while it is either related to the receiver or to a mix of questions related to both the sender (SendMail, in this case) and the receiver.

Thanks for any suggestion or diagnostic indication.

Best wishes,

Carmine

.. I solved by myself and here I place problem and solution so that it may help others:

- I had this code, to send email with HTML content:

  ```
  $mailing_list = & JFactory::getMailer ();

  for ($i = 0; $i < count ($recipients_mailing_list); $i++) {

    if (substr_count ($recipients_mailing_list[$i], '@')) {

    $sent_ok = $mailing_list->sendMail ('info@my_domain', 'my_domain', $recipients_mailing_list[$i], $email_ref, htmlspecialchars_decode ($email_body), TRUE);

    }
  }
  ```

.. and it processed the sending so that any new recipient processed also send again the previous one.
i.e.: if I had an array of 3 recipients, the first one received the email 3 times, twice for the second and the last one is the only who receive a single email.

I solved it moving the declaration JFactory::getMailer () into the for loop so that it renew the "instance construction" and clean it, as follows:

```
    for ($i = 0; $i < count ($recipients_mailing_list); $i++) {

      if (substr_count ($recipients_mailing_list[$i], '@')) {

      $mailing_list = & JFactory::getMailer ();

      $sent_ok = $mailing_list->sendMail ('info@my_domain', 'my_domain', $recipients_mailing_list[$i], $email_ref, htmlspecialchars_decode ($email_body), TRUE);

      }
    }
```

It is not very efficient, at the code side, but it works ok.

Is there any better way to solve it?

Thanks for any suggestion will come.

Best wishes,

Carmine

Answer (score 0):

Joomla 2.5 Mail function as follow.

It returns **true on success** or a **JError object**.  so, your condition should be as below.

$send =& $mailer->Send();

if ( $send !== true ) {

```
echo 'Error sending email: ' . $send->message;
```

} else {

```
echo 'Mail sent';
```

}

You will check more detail on joomla documentation using below link.
http://docs.joomla.org/Sending_email_from_extensions

Hope this solution work for you.